# How can I read 'utf-8' text file in R?

Tags: r, encoding

I need to read text file in `R`.

so I used "`read.delim()".`

It works well when I read text file encoded `ASCII`

but  I can't read `UTF-8`

so I have to encode the text file to `ASCII`

*how can I encode text files to "ASCII" in R?*

the warning message below present when I read `utf-8` text file.

It seems file path isn't read

Warning messages:

```
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/?곗씠?곕텇??OB留μ＜/02.INPUT_DB_query_data/POC?곗씠??DRAFT/DRAFT_20110105.txt'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/?곗씠?곕텇??OB留μ＜/02.INPUT_DB_query_data/POC?곗씠??DRAFT/DRAFT_20110105.txt'
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  header and 'col.names' are of different lengths
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `encoding="UTF-8"` to read the `UTF-8` file?

Answer (score 4):

Try with `encoding='UTF-8'`

```
read.delim(file='filename',
           encoding='UTF-8'
           #Other settings
           )
```

I hope this will work....