# How to read utf-8 encoded text in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm importing .xlsx files in to R and when I enter print data command I get a mess with specific symbols. The file opens nicely with excel. This is the code I use:

`library("xlsx")
data <-read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
print(data)`

Comment: See `encoding` part here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Comment: "importing .xlsx files in to R" - please show us the code. Maybe duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879521/how-can-i-read-utf-8-text-file-in-r) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read data in utf-8 format in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r)

Comment: Which package are you using for the data extraction? you can't just `read.csv()` an Excel file. You need to use one of the half-dozen or so Excel pkgs to actually get Excel data into R.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have access to your data so I cannot check:

```
data <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: It works, it's checked