# R -read data frame from excel with greek characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read in Ran excel file where some column names contain the characters "μg".
It appears with chinese characters in R.
What could be a solution please?

Comment: Have you tried with `read_excel` with encoding option

Comment: I am loading the excel file as workbook, so I am using the openxlsx library, and I do not see any encoding options.

Comment: those options are only in certain packages.

Comment: Eg. you may try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176027/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-text-in-r